# Invention of the concept of vector field

Tags: mathematics

I'm very interested to know how the concept of vector field was created. What problems or phenomena led mathematicians to introduce the concept of vector field?

Answer (score 3):

I would point to Euler's [*Principes généraux du mouvement des fluides*](http://bibliothek.bbaw.de/bbaw/bibliothek-digital/digitalequellen/schriften/anzeige/index_html?band=02-hist/1755&seite:int=282), Mém. Acad. Sci. Berlin **11 (1755)** (1757) 274-315 for a pretty clear notion of a fluid's velocity field (whose integral curves are the lines of flow, and satisfying what we now call Euler's equations and the continuity equation).

O. Darrigol in [*Worlds of flow: A history of hydrodynamics from the Bernoullis to Prandtl*](http://books.google.com/books?id=H-E0_-X_h2wC&pg=PA25) has some of this anticipated in earlier memoirs of Euler and D'Alembert, but I find the modern concept quite a bit harder to identify there.